# HSQLDB function creating Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException:

Tags: java, junit, hsqldb

ISSUE:

I am using `HSQLDB` as inmemory database for my testing, I am able to execute tables  fine, I am getting below exception when I tried to create the function and run.

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: 54   org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file: CREATE FUNCTION get_mask() 
                    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
```

Test script for hypersonic:

```
            SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB2467A82B33
            SET DATABASE GC 0
            SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
            SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
            SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
            SET DATABASE SQL REGULAR NAMES TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
            SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
            SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL NULLS FIRST TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
            SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
            SET DATABASE SQL LONGVAR IS LOB FALSE
            SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
            SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
            SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
            SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
            SET FILES WRITE DELAY 0
            SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT FALSE
            SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
            SET FILES CACHE ROWS 2000
            SET FILES SCALE 64
            SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
            SET FILES DEFRAG 0
            SET FILES NIO FALSE
            SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
            SET FILES LOG TRUE
            SET FILES LOG SIZE 0
            SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
            CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
            CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
            SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
            CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.EMPLOYEEDETAILS(EMPNAME VARCHAR(20))
            CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.VW_OH_MKT_OFFERS(MKT_OFFER_UID VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,INTENT VARCHAR(3),LEGACY_OFFER_CODE VARCHAR(12),PRODUCT_LINE_CODE VARCHAR(10),STATUS VARCHAR(1),BEGIN_DATE DATE,END_DATE DATE,SOURCE_KEY_UID VARCHAR(12),SOURCE_KEY_CODE VARCHAR(20),PT_CODE VARCHAR(12),OFFER_GROUP_CODE VARCHAR(12),OFFER_CODE VARCHAR(12),ITEM_CODE VARCHAR(30),VENUE_CODE VARCHAR(20),SUPERVENUE_CODE VARCHAR(12),CURRENCY_CODE VARCHAR(3),INITIAL_UNIT_PRICE DECIMAL(10,2),INITIAL_NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS NUMERIC(10),INITIAL_FIRST_PAYMENT_AMOUNT DECIMAL(10,2),INITIAL_FIRST_SHIPPING_AMOUNT DECIMAL(10,2),INITIAL_STD_SHIPPING NUMERIC(128),INITIAL_STD_SHIP_AVAILABLE VARCHAR(1),INITIAL_RUSH_SHIPPING DECIMAL(10,2),INITIAL_RUSH_SHIP_AVAILABLE VARCHAR(1),INITIAL_2DAY_SHIPPING NUMERIC(128),INITIAL_2DAY_SHIP_AVAILABLE VARCHAR(1),INITIAL_SDAY_SHIPPING NUMERIC(128),INITIAL_SDAY_SHIP_AVAILABLE VARCHAR(1),INITIAL_REG_NAME VARCHAR(2),INITIAL_REG_STD_SHIPPING NUMERIC(128),INITIAL_REG_STD_SHIP_AVAILABLE VARCHAR(1),WEB_CART_TITLE VARCHAR(30),WEB_CART_TEXT VARCHAR(30),WEB_CART_IMAGE VARCHAR(30),WEB_CART_MAX_QUANTITY VARCHAR(30),FFC_CODE VARCHAR(100),MULTI_NODE_SHIPPING_LOCATION VARCHAR(60),ITEM_CONTINUITY_CODE VARCHAR(30),OMX_CID VARCHAR(30),OMX_KEYCODE VARCHAR(30),OMX_PAYMENT_PLAN_ID VARCHAR(30),OMX_SOC_CONFIGURATION_ID VARCHAR(30),HP_KEY_CODE VARCHAR(20),HP_PRODUCT_NUMBER VARCHAR(20),HP_MPG_CODE VARCHAR(10),LEGACY_SCRIPT_CODE VARCHAR(12),TENANT_ID BIGINT)
            ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
            SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
            GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
            GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
            GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
            GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
            GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
            GRANT DBA TO SA
            SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
            INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEDETAILS VALUES('Test1')
            INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEDETAILS VALUES('Test2')
            INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEDETAILS VALUES('Test3')
            INSERT INTO VW_OH_MKT_OFFERS VALUES('1142675','TLM','DR1138','PA','C','2008-08-22','2008-08-22','YYYY-MM-DD','34DUN','KPA510C34DUN','PPAJ9R','HPADJPT','OPA18RAG','PA1467','28','5',29.22,1,29.95,5.99,6,'1',5.99,'1',0,'0',0,'0','CA',0,'1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'EDS',NULL,NULL,NULL,'34DUN',NULL,NULL,'558358','014399','300','DR11',1);
            CREATE FUNCTION get_mask() 
            RETURNS VARCHAR(3)
            BEGIN ATOMIC
            DECLARE max_event VARCHAR(3); 
            SET intent = SELECT INTENT FROM VW_OH_MKT_OFFERS WHERE MKT_OFFER_UID='1142675'; 
            RETURN intent;
            END
```

Java Code:

```
                           //Java code to execute stored proc
                        Connection connection = null;
                             // resultset
                        ResultSet resultSet = null;
                        Statement statement = null;
                      // driver creation
                        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");

                                                    // connect to the db                                           

connection =                                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:\\HyperSQLDB\\EMPLOYEEDB;shutdown=true", "SA", "");


            // getting statement    

statement = connection.createStatement();

            // create callable statement for calling function
                        CallableStatement stat = connection.prepareCall("{call get_mask()}");
                // Check if the function is executed
                        System.out.println(stat.execute()); // => true
            // get the result
                        ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();
            // get the next result
                        rs.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is generated and used by the database engine. You should not add text to the script or modify it in a text editor.

You should execute the SQL statement below after connecting to the database via JDBC:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_mask() 
RETURNS VARCHAR(3)
BEGIN ATOMIC
   DECLARE max_event VARCHAR(3); 
   SET intent = SELECT INTENT FROM VW_OH_MKT_OFFERS WHERE MKT_OFFER_UID='1142675'; 
   RETURN intent;
END
```